# Why get org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public class SeleniumExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      System.err.println("Driver");

      driver.get("http://www.google.com");
      System.err.println("Driver get");

      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
      element.submit();
      System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

      (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
        }
    });
    // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

I am newbie with Selenium...and i dont know why I get this exception....i have the latest 50.1.0 with the latest firefox selenium driver 3.0.1, and i donw know why i get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
at SeleniumExample.main(SeleniumExample.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: You have issue with dependency, Looks like you are calling old version. Are you using Maven if yes then use mvn dependency it will auto resolve your issue.

Comment: Iam using maven and I add 3.01 firefox drriver,selenium-server but nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `geckodriver` for `Firefox` in `selenium 3.0` as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Utils\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```